# How to handle spaces in file names in ProFTPD xferlog?

Tags: urlencode, proftpd

I’m watching the xferlog of ProFTPD in `/var/log/proftpd/xferlog` and would like to generate valid URLs (the folder is served by Apache) of the logged entries. Spaces in paths get replaced with `_` which should be rather `%20` url encoded.

```
Fri Apr 16 03:27:10 2021 9388 gwe235gdfg.sad.isp.com 25399323775 /home/public_html/Filename_with_spaces.mxf b _ i r user@ftp.mydomain.com sftp 0 * c
```

Note `Filename_with_spaces.mxf` is actually `Filename with spaces.mxf`. How can I configure ProFTPD to log URL encoded file paths?

Answer (score 0):

You currently cannot; ProFTPD does not currently have support for using URL encoded filenames in the `xferlog(5)` format.  You can request such a feature by opening a ticket at *e.g.* https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/issues.